# Dúvida com bool em C

Tags: c

Bem, fiz esse teste com vetores, mas estou tendo problema com o tipo bool, que nunca fica falso e exibe a mensagem de não encontrada.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main() {

    char *palavras[] = {"maca", "uva", "pera"};
    int tamanho = sizeof(palavras) / sizeof(char *);
    int tam = tamanho;
    char nome[100];
    bool achou = false;

    while(true) {
    if(tam > 0) {
    printf("[ ");
    for(int i=0; i<tam - 1; i++) {
        printf("%s, ", palavras[i]);
    }
       printf("%s ]\n", palavras[tam - 1]);
    }
    printf("Deseja excluir qual fruta? ");
    fgets(nome, 20, stdin);
    nome[strlen(nome) - 1] = '\0';
    if(tam == 0) { puts("Sem frutas disponiveis"); break; }
    for(int i=0; i<tam; i++) {
    achou = false;
    if(!strcmp(nome, palavras[i])) {
        printf("Fruta: %s, excluida.\n\n", nome);
        for(int j=i; j<tam - 1; j++) {
            palavras[j] = palavras[j + 1];
        }
        tam--;
        achou = true;
        break;
     }
    if(achou) { //se falso
        printf("Fruta: %s, nao encontrada.\n\n", nome);
    } } }

    return 0;
}
```

Não consigo solucionar isso.

Comment: Por que você remove a última letra do nome da fruta que o usuário entra, na linha 24?

Comment: Você está se referindo ao fgets?

Comment: A linha imediatamente abaixo do `fgets()`

Comment: nome[strlen(nome) - 1] = '\0'; , mas isso vai remover o '\n', sem ele a comparação não daria certo.

Comment: Tem razão; é o `gets()` que não incui o retorno de carro na _string_ que retorna. Compilei o seu código aqui e ele funcionou corretamente, no entanto. Não parece haver erro nenhum nele.

Comment: ```if (achou) { // se falso``` não deveria ser ```if (!achou) { // se falso``` ? E talvez deveria estar fora do for esse if.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Eu editei o seu programa

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main()
{

  char *palavras[] = {"maca", "uva", "pera"};
  int tamanho = sizeof(palavras) / sizeof(char *);
  int tam = tamanho;
  char nome[100];
  bool achou = false;
  while(true)
    {
      if(tam > 0)
        {
          printf("[ ");
          for(int i=0; i<tam - 1; i++)
            {
              printf("%s, ", palavras[i]);
            }
          printf("%s ]\n", palavras[tam - 1]);
        }
      printf("Deseja excluir qual fruta? ");
      fgets(nome, 20, stdin);
      nome[strlen(nome) - 1] = '\0';
      if(tam == 0)
        {
          puts("Sem frutas disponiveis");
          break;
        }
      for(int i=0; i<tam; i++)
        {
          achou = false;
          if(!strcmp(nome, palavras[i]))
            {
              printf("Fruta: %s, excluida.\n\n", nome);
              for(int j=i; j<tam - 1; j++)
                {
                  palavras[j] = palavras[j + 1];
                }
              tam--;
              achou = true;
              break;
            }
        }
      if(!achou) // retirado de dentro do for e na negativa
        { //se falso
          printf("Fruta: %s, nao encontrada.\n\n", nome);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, então apesar de declarar a variável achou = false; no if por padrão será true?

Comment: se achar a palavra, fica true. Caso não achar, fica false. Como é (!achou), então se achar a palavra, não entra no if, e se não achar, entra no if.

Comment: queria entender o porque do -1?

Comment: Esse site esta cheio de gente arrogante.

Comment: Até aí, eu entendo a preocupação dos caras de manter um site limpo, com perguntas e respostas respeitando o formato [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour). O problema é negativar e nem sabermos onde erramos. Pois, errar é humano.

Comment: @lemoce , creio que sua negativação tenha se dado por você não ter explicado a resposta, apenas apresentado um código alterado.

Comment: Vou editá-la. Obrigado @JeffersonQuesado.